# Connect through ssh to a server which I can log in with a web login

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

There is a server or cluster of computers to which I have access via a web page. I log in with my username and password and then I have a terminal, the same way I would have if I connected through ssh. I would like to bypass this web login and connect directly through ssh, although I don't know whether this is possible or not.
If I go to /etc/ssh the uncommented lines of sshd_config are:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile          .ssh/authorized_keys    
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UseDNS no
Match Adress *,!XXX.YY.ZZ.W/PP
    PermitRootLogin yes
    AllowGroups root sudo admin
```

So in principle I think this should be possible, note that I don't have root or sudo. 
Things I have tried:

- To connect with ssh to one of the ips of the computers in the cluster (that I know because I can ssh to them once I'm inside the cluster) and port PP
- To connect with ssh to the ip shown if I run `who` in the terminal
- To connect with ssh to the name of the webpage where I log in

In all cases ssh (with debug info) gets stuck at "Connecting to XXX.YY.ZZ.W port PP"

`ps aux | grep sshd` shows that `/usr/sbin/sshd` -D is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the intricacies of the site, but in general you can't do this - HTTP(s) and SSH are entirely different protocols, and do not share information with each other - although often they will share a common source of truth for login information (eg single signon or ldap or radius or kerberos etc).

If it is possible to access the website without a password from the machine you are SSH'ing to however (which could be possible by using IP based authentication in addition to other authentication) then yes, you could do this - The easiest way might be to set up your computer to use a SOCKS proxy, and have SSH act as the SOCKS proxy - which is more-or-less part of the protocol.   I don't think this is a likely scenario though.